# Counting how many primes exists between square root of a given range .

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I am given a range say $l,r$ ( with $1 \leq l,r \leq 10^{14}$).

I am also given a cumulative count of prime numbers that exists between $1$ and $10^7$ .

For example :

- For $1$ count=$0$ (as no primes exist up to $1$)
- For $2$ count=$1$
- For $3$ count=$2$
- For $  4 $ count=$2$
- For $5$ count=$3$ ( this corresponds to the primes $2,3$ and $5$).

Can I use the value of these counts to get the number of primes that exist between $\sqrt{l}$ and $\sqrt{r}$? .
Example :

For say a query for $l,r$ where $l=1$ and $r=100$ .The answer will be $4 $ as $\sqrt{1}=1$ ,  $\sqrt{100}=10$ and between $1$ and $10$ there are $4$ primes $2,3,5,7$.

Comment: Number of primes between $a$ and $b$ equal to $\pi(b)-\pi(a)$ ($\pi$ is prime-counting function)

Comment: Its isn't true..for case like 9,9..it will give 0 as answer,but answer will be 1.

Comment: If both limits are inclusive, $\pi(\sqrt{r}) - \pi(\lceil\sqrt{l}\rceil - 1)$.

Comment: Thanks daniel,it worked..i was trying to find out the relation since the last 1 hr..it will be great if you can explain how did you reached this?

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 0):

Use the Prime Number Theorem : If p(x) is the number of primes less than x, then p(x).ln(x)/x converges to 1 as x goes to infinity. This is a deep and difficult result. The approximation to 1 is pretty good even for 100 < x < 1000.